# Op Amp Oscillation BPW34 Radiation detection

Tags: oscillation, operational-amplifier

I have build the following circuit on a stripboard

[image]

Now the problem is, even if I do not have the BPW34 diode attached my output shows a nice sqaure wave as you can see here
[image]

But I have no idea where to start how to analyze where this comes from or why this happens. So I am very grateful for any ideas how to approach this problem. One addiational thing: I did not use the 330k Resisitors instead I used 300k resistors. Edit: The transistor is a BF245B.

Here you can see my stripboard. [image]

[image]

This blue thing in the upper picture is a capacitor which is not connected. And remember: The BPW diode is missing but when it is soldered on the board and made lightproof it also starts oscillating with the same frequency and amplitude.

Comment: That could quite easily pickup stuff like the AC hum from power lines if the wiring is too long.  What does your strip board look like? (post a picture)

Comment: Where did the design come from? Is it from a reputable source? What power supply did you use? Did you use the specified op-amp? Where are the supply decouplers for the op-amp? How awful might your strip board be when you have an AC gain of about 900?

Comment: Why the radiation symbol?

Comment: @JRE This was also my idea so I shielded the whole circuit with aluminum foil and grounded the foil but there was no difference. I did not know that the circuit can pickup AC hum

Comment: @Andyaka Yes from here [link](https://www.element14.com/community/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadBody/41953-102-1-229709/Elektor%20Radiation%20Meter.pdf). I googled and some people have this problem with oscillation. Power suppy was a 9V battery and my lab power supply but there wasn't any difference and yes I used the specified op-amp.

Comment: @Finbarr It represents a radiactive source, the purpose of the circuit is to detect ionizing radiation.

Comment: Double check all components and look for shorts between tracks. Run it in a metal tin (connected to battery negative) as shown in the article, ensuring the tracks are insulated from the can. Try a 12V lead acid battery rather than 9V PP3. Stripboard per se is not a problem - I successfully ran a similar circuit on breadboard in a foil bag.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the original PCB design from Elektor: -

[image]

It's a double sided board with a full coverage ground plane on the component side and a partial ground plane on the solder side. These ground planes are probably quite fundamental in achieving low noise and stability given that the circuit has an AC gain of 900.

You'd have to be at the top of your game to make this work consistently on strip board or just plain lucky.

Comment: Ok thank you. If there are no other good ways to shield a perfboard i think I cannot make it work. At least I tried :-D

Comment: Try minimising the tracks on pins 2 and 6. It might help.

Comment: Try manhattan style construction ...

Answer (score 1):

It works. I only use a 10M\Omega Resistor from diode to ground instead of 20M\Omega so I think the Fet was biased wrong. I also put the whole stripboard into a metal case.
[image]

Look at this beautiful picture :-) 
If someone could enlighten me why only using a 10M\Omega from diode to ground works but 20M\Omega does not work....this would be great.